# Specifying the radius distance for latitude and longitude in Instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, instafeedjs

Is there a way to specify the radius distance of the lat + long locationID in instafeed.js?

For example the following code will return photos tagged with the location for the Eiffel Tower and then filtered for some hashtag. Is there a way to specify a radius of say a few kilometers or something like that around the location point?

```
var mylocation = 54115074; //must be a number! 

var feed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'location',
  locationId: mylocation,

  clientId: 'someId', //change this with the client id you get from Instagram

  filter: function(image) {
    return (image.tags.indexOf('myTag') >= 0);
  }
});
feed.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instafeed.js does not support this functionality just yet. However, the current Instagram API does. If you navigate here:

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/

The API documentation does a good job of describing how to do this.

What you are looking for is the **"Location Search"** query. In this query, you pass the lat and long coordinates for the location in question. Then simply provide an additional parameter for distance.